# Cannot hide title bar using .windowStyle

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I developed an application for macOS that initially runs in the Menu Bar. In this View, an Edit button opens an additional window. I open it through the command:

```
openWindow(id: "settings-window")
```

Before that, I used NSWindow for these purposes, but there was an error with the fact that I could open several identical windows. And now, I do not know how to hide the title and the buttons for closing, collapsing, and opening the application. I tried to apply:

```
.windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
```

or

```
.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
```

But nothing helps. How can I hide these extra elements?

[image: Here is an image, what I've got]

Tried to use `.windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)` and `.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())`.

Comment: If Swift supports in-line CSS you could style='display:none;"  But I suspect Swift exists specifically not to do CSS like that, but I'm sure there is a similar command just in the this.that format.  Now that I think about it, does it support javascript?  You could use a single line to close the element by Element ID using that as another option.